# Is it possible to calculate a limit by evaluating a definite sum?

Tags: limits, summation

I'm wondering if there is a **general method** for transforming any limit into a definite sum.  Of course, an indefinite sum may be able to represent a limit, so I am wondering if a definite or finite sum can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

By definite sum I suppose you mean a sum of finitely many terms. Generally the answer is no. No general method for all cases. There are numerous techniques and theorems for evaluating  various kinds of limits. Showing that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt { x+1}-x=0$  is easy. If $P(x)$ is the number of primes less than $x$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} P(x)/( x \ln x)=1$ , which is the Prime Number Theorem, one of the most deep and difficult results in mathematics.Another hard one is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^2)= \pi^2/6$. There is no known analogous "simple general formula" for $\zeta (k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1/n^k)$ for $k \in \{3,5,7,9,...\}$ unless you call the $\zeta$ (zeta) function "simple".